# Configuring AWS::Serverless::Api resources for HTTP_PROXY integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, serverless-application-model

Using the console, I was able to configure an API gateway method to pass HTTP requests with a path parameter off to a another URI.

The result looks as follows
[image]

This would make it so that my request is forwarded to `https://example.com` with the same (greedy) path parameter.

Though this was successful enough, I need to be able to be able to specify this as an AWS::Serverless::Api resource in a cloudformation template. As far as I can tell, [the documentation for the Serverless Application Model](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi) does not provide any mention as to how to accomplish this.

Can it be done on a serverless resource, or do I need to work with traditional AWS::ApiGateway::Resource/Method's?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found is to create a swagger definition using `DefinitionBody`, here is an example, so you can get an idea. [Repo](https://github.com/ntwobike/serverless-api/blob/master/template.yaml)

**IMPORTANT**: if you use the proxy integration on Lambda, `httpMethod` method in the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` should be `POST` regardless your method `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` or `DELETE` => `httpMethod: POST`

```
DefinitionBody: 
    swagger: 2.0
    info:
      title: EventSource API Definition
    paths:
      /events/{id}:
        get:
          summary: Get an event details
          description: Retrieve specific event
          parameters:
          - name: id
            in: path
            required: true
            type: string
          consumes:
            - application/json
          produces:
            - application/json
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            uri:                  
              Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetEventsFunction.Arn}/invocations
            responses: {}
            httpMethod: POST
            type: aws_proxy
```

Comment: Isn't the `httpMethod: POST` requirement only for lambda proxy integration?

Comment: Brody is asking for a http_proxy integration, this is an aws_proxy integration